# container for image on iphone

Tags: iphone, button

i want to pop up a circular ring whenever user press base button and that ciruclar ring should have 6 buttons on corner and each button should have its own function upon click.

but i dont know how to put those 6 buttons.

so on screen there will be 4 base button and user can click any of the 4 to pop that circular ring (with 6 buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Keep the buttons separate from the ring.

The ring is just a graphical element (`UIImageView`) on which the six `UIButton` instances sit atop.

Make the ring and its buttons subviews of a parent view. Use the `frame` property to set their position and size.

Your first "top-most" button could have a selector that then unhides the ring and the six buttons:

```
- (void) unhideButtonRing:(id)sender {
    ringElement.hidden = NO;
    buttonOne.hidden = NO;
    ...
    buttonSix.hidden = NO;
}
```

You could use an `NSTimer` to hide the button-ring after some time period.

Comment: so you want me to put mannually those buttons ... but lets say i have 4 base buttons on screen and each base button on click should display that ring ..with all 6 buttions and method ... its will be too messy to write coordinate.. plz help me i am dead :( any code or any link

Comment: You could write a `UIView` subclass that draws a ring of buttons. You can then make as many rings as you want, and place them anywhere you want.

Comment: you method is working but DO I need to write all ring coordinates???

if i hve 7 rings then 7 *6coordintes??? that too manually

Comment: how to draw rings of buttons
??

Comment: - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
 NSLog(@"just cvcvccvcvcclicked");
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
    [button setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:button];
 
}


you mean like this i have to make 6 buttons??

Comment: Yep. Or use Interface Builder.

Comment: so you mean if i have to show 4 base button then i have to write 
4*6= 24 buttons coordinates???

Comment: Not if you set the button-ring frame values relative to the base buttons. When you instantiate your custom UIView, pass it the base button coordinates and draw the view relative to the base button.

Comment: do i need to draw 6 buttons on drawRect()??